# What determines the number of Adsense advert in a page?

Tags: google-adsense

I have a chicken farming blog. My blog is doing very well in terms of traffic. My problem is that that I am getting one advert per page.  I have a lot of content. I have seen other blogs with less content but a larger number of adverts is showing. One chicken farming page i checked it had 5 different adverts showing. What can I do to get a larger number of adverts?

Comment: Are you using AdSense auto ads, or are you using placements to put ads where you want them?

Answer (score 1):

You can place as many units as you want, wherever you want, in the website code (just don't overdoit!).
Right now I assume that you either used the code that lets adsense decide or you only have a single unit set in your template.